# mysql trigger to remove non-numeric characters from string

Tags: mysql, numeric, trim

Is there a way to remove all non-numeric characters from a nvarchar text string in MySQL?

I kind of got it working with the following select statement but I am having issues on getting the UPDATE statement so I can use the UPDATE on a MySQL trigger everytime something gets inserted or updated. I need to remove the dash "-" and any spaces and only leave all the numeric characters.

Here is a sample of the table structure.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90668/7/0

The field that contain all the dashes and the spaces is  'locationNumber'.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Why not simply use an integer data type?

Comment: I wish I could do that. They have a program and if I make it an integer it adds commas after three characters.

Comment: @eggyal Do you think that there is a way to do this?

Comment: Why not do your `REPLACE()` on `INSERT`?